# How to Connect to VSS using C# Programmatically?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a application where i need to connect to the VSS at server using C# programming.Please suggest me some idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VSS automation
[Sample code here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3khk6k6(VS.80).aspx)